# Custom drupal ajax forms based on content type cck

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, forms, view

Why hello there Stackoverflow,

I have a nutcracker for ya, is there an "good" way to create 100% custom forms or rather just textboxes and have the values sent to an url like so: http://site/drupal/formreciever-content-type , post-sending the values of X textboxes with jQuery for example? Without having to do so much backend work, right now various solutions exists but none that does exatly what I need.

I want to be able to make a site based entirely on views, so the structure is completely changed. Then for the content types I want to be able to just manually add some text fields etc to the html where needed and there make a custom submit button that jquery uses to just form-submit or send the values to some "drupal reciever" with some parameter for the name of the content type etc and drupal takes care of the rest.

That would be optimal, if it's possible, or if anyone know any sort of similar thing please do tell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe, seems like something you would normally do by coding your own module. I doubt you will find anything module that can assist you in something so special and customized.

That being said, with some help from the Drupal FAPI, it shouldn't be to hard, to code your own module to do the above. All you really need is a form with some text fields and and callback to receive your jQuery AJAX.